# Expected value of $f(x)=\frac38 x^2$ with range $[0,2]$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I was going through some examples of finding the expected value of continuous random variables and i found an example as below.

[image]

Could anyone please explain how the working shown works as I'm really confused on how the power value is incremented.

Comment: $xf(x) = x \cdot \left(\frac{3}{8}x^2\right) = \frac{3}{8}x^3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for the expected value of continuous random variables is definded as:
\begin{equation}
E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx
\end{equation}
where $f_X(x)$ is the density of $X$ and $X$ is a continuous random variable. For the example, $\displaystyle f_X(x)=\frac{3}{8}x^2,x\in[0,2],f_X(x)=0,x \notin [0,2].\rightarrow E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx=\int_{0}^{2}x\frac{3}{8}x^2dx=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3}{8}x^3dx=\frac{3}{8}\frac{x^4}{4}|_0^2$.

Could you understand better?

Comment: Three $x$ vs $X$ confusions, please correct these.

Comment: I'm sorry. $X$ means random variable generally and I have edit again.

Comment: Still two wrong occurrences at present.

Comment: Why not correct these?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I could not find where you point.

Comment: "maybe I could not find where you point." And maybe this is a lie since you just corrected them... Why the obstruction?

Comment: hhhh……Actually,I found them after I added the last comment. I did not find out at first…… Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In general,

$$\int x^n \, dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C, n \ne -1$$

A proof of the result can be found [here](http://planetmath.org/integrationofpolynomial).

In the question $n$ was $3$.

If the doubt is where does power $3$ comes from, we get it by multiplying $x$ with $f(x)$.